Navigation to multiple pages cause a runtime error
I have four pages but for now let's say I have three pages; Page1, Page2, and Page3. Navigating to these three (or more) different pages in any order returns an error:
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 

In Actuality the error message is much longer than that though, but i figured it's enough.
Edit: I changed the layouts from Grid to FlexLayout and now it crashes my compiler and gives this stack trace:
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: View with id -1: crc640ec207abc449b2ca.ShellPageContainer#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()

  --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalStateException stack trace ---
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View with id -1: crc640ec207abc449b2ca.ShellPageContainer#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()

Here are the pages involved:
var Page1 = new VerticalStackLayout()
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};
var Page2 = new FlexLayout()
{
    AlignItems = FlexAlignItems.Center,
    Direction = FlexDirection.Column,
    WidthRequest = screen.Width / screen.Density
};
var Page3 = new FlexLayout()
{
    AlignItems = FlexAlignItems.Center,
    Direction = FlexDirection.Column,
    WidthRequest = screen.Width / screen.Density
};

Edit 2: Here's how I navigate to pages:
btn1.Pressed += delegate
{
    Content = Page1;
};
btn2.Pressed += delegate
{
    Content = Page2;
};
btn3.Pressed += delegate
{
    Content = Page3;
};

Changing Page1, Page2 or Page3 to null works fine, so the problem might be in the pages.
Edit 3:
When Page1, Page2 or Page3 has no children, it works fine, except that I can't navigate to other pages, so the problem might be in the buttons.

This question needs a few more details. I see it's tagged .net, but the language is Java. Is this MAUI for a mobile app? Something else? Clarify the context, please. Anyway, you also don't show exactly how you are navigating between the pages. It sounds like you are trying to use the same page instance every time, whereas you should either create a new instance each time, or do as the error message says and remove the view (page) from the previous parent before navigating to it under the new parent.

@Leandro Yes indeed, it is MAUI for a mobile app; to navigate to other pages I do Content = desiredPage; when pressing a button. Also your suggested solution is irrelevant, since I've changed the layout from Grid to FlexLayout.

"Java.Lang.IllegalStateException:" Perhaps update your tags to get some Java people visibility to this
